# Django pagination throwing an error when trying to go to the next page

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

I'm currently working on a project that will display advertisements on a website. I'm facing some level of difficulty even after researching for half a day trying to find a solution but with no luck.

I have a `HomeView` which inherits the `ListView` where I have  `paginate_by = 30` and this displays on the home page and works as it should in terms of going to whatever page number I click on.

I have another view called `NegotiableAdView` which also inherits the `ListView`. In this view I'm getting a value from `request.GET` which is either ***yes*** or ***no*** then filter the queryset accordingly to return. It displays the number of ads I set the `paginate_by` attribute to, but the problem is whenever I click on `page 2` or whatever page number it is saying for example:

> Page not found (404)... Invalid page (2): That page contains no
> results

I'm not sure why it's giving that error. But do I have the following...

Within the `html` file containing the form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'store:search-negotiation' %}">
     <div id="collapseThreee" class="panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThreee">
          <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="skin-minimal">
                    <ul class="list">
                         <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="radio-yes" name="negotiable" value="Yes">
                              <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="radio-no" name="negotiable" value="No">
                              <label for="no">No</label>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Within the `urls.py` file:

```
from .views import NegotiableAdView

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('search-negotiation/', NegotiableAdView.as_view(), name='search-negotiation'),
    ...
]
```

Within the `views.py` file:

```
class NegotiableAdView(ListView):
     context_object_name = 'ads'
     paginate_by = 12
     template_name = 'store/pages/results.html'

     def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
          negotiable = self.request.GET.get('negotiable')

          queryset = Advertisement.objects.filter(negotiable__iexact=negotiable).order_by('-publish', 'name')

          return queryset

     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
          negotiable = self.request.GET.get('negotiable')

          # This 'negotiable' var is only not none when on the first page of the results
          if negotiable:
               context['result_name'] = f'Results "{negotiable.title()}"'

          return context
```

Within the `results.html` file which includes the `pagination`:

```
{% for ad in ads %}
    ...
{% endfor %}


{% include 'store/includes/pagination.html' with pages=page_obj %}
```

Within the `pagination.html` file:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
        {% if pages.has_previous %}
            <li>
                <a href="?page={{ pages.previous_page_number }}">« Previous Page</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% if pages.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}
            <li>
                <a href="?page={{ pages.number|add:'-5' }}">&hellip;</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% for number in pages.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if pages.number == number %}
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">{{ number }}</a>
                </li>
            {% elif number > pages.number|add:'-5' and number < pages.number|add:'5' %}
                <li>
                    <a href="?page={{ number }}">{{ number }}</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if pages.paginator.num_pages > pages.number|add:'4' %}
            <li>
                <a href="?page={{ pages.number|add:'5' }}">&hellip;</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        {% if pages.has_next %}
            <li>
                <a href="?page={{ pages.next_page_number }}">Next Page »</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Also to note, my `url` on the results page if the user selects ***yes***, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-negotiation/?negotiable=Yes`. But when the user clicks on `page 2` for example, I'm seeing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search-negotiation/?page=2` with the error being displayed as stated earlier.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong, please? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got an idea, tried it and it worked! I assume this might not be the most efficient way of getting this solved for the particular problem I was having, but this was what I did.

So with I've created a new `url` in the `url.py` file.

```
 urlpatterns = [
      ...
      path('search/', RedirectedSearchView.as_view(), name='search'), # new url
      path('search-negotiation/<str:negotiable>/', NegotiableAdView.as_view(), name='search-negotiation'), # update this url for kwargs.
      ...
 ]
```

The form will send the `GET` request to be handled at the new `url`, where it also will be redirected accordingly.

The form:

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'store:search' %}"> <!-- updated url here -->
     <div id="collapseThreee" class="panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThreee">
          <div class="panel-body">
               <div class="skin-minimal">
                    <ul class="list">
                         <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="radio-yes" name="negotiable" value="Yes">
                              <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                              <input type="radio" id="radio-no" name="negotiable" value="No">
                              <label for="no">No</label>
                         </li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Within the `views.py` file:

```
# This view will handle the GET request and then redirect to the necessary view.
class RedirectedSearchView(TemplateView):
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          # Doing a check here to see if the form made a GET request by trying to get a value submitted
          if request.GET.get('negotiable'):
               # As I do the redirect, I must pass a 'negotiable' value to the url
               # Assigning the value passed from the request.GET -> negotiable=request.GET.get('negotiable').lower()

               return redirect('store:search-negotiation', negotiable=request.GET.get('negotiable').lower())

          return redirect('store:home')

class NegotiableAdView(ListView):
     context_object_name = 'ads'
     paginate_by = 12
     template_name = 'store/pages/results.html'

     def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
          # Collecting the value from the url to filter the queryset to return
          negotiable = self.kwargs.get('negotiable', '')

          return Advertisement.objects.filter(negotiable__iexact=negotiable).order_by('-publish', 'name')

 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      negotiable = self.kwargs.get('negotiable', '')

      context['result_name'] = f'Results "{negotiable.title()}"'

      return context
```

By doing it this way, my `pagination` is now going to the other pages as it wasn't doing before.

As I said, this solution might not be the most efficient solution. Therefore, I'm open to receiving something more efficient and the correct way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!